# Automation of object selection to be printed in data driven page?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, select, data-driven-pages, layouts

Is it possible to have the central object of each DDP to be automatically selected in order to be visually enhanced?

The part of segment being the main cartographic object within the page, should have another visual properties than the upstream or downstream parts.

Answer (score 2):

To do this I would:

1. Copy your index layer in the table of contents and set its symbology to however you wish to highlight that polygon
2. Set a Page Definition Query on the Definition Query tab of the Properties for the "copy of your Index" layer to keep the feature that matches it

and that's it!